# Template of vector in C++ compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, vector

This is the code I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace std;

class   Vector
{
 // Use user defined template class for vector handling
    template <class V,class D>
    void vec_add(V &vec, D data)
    {
            vec.push_back(data);
    }
};

int main ()
{
        vector<int> v;  // v is vecor of int elements

        Vector.vec_add(&v,222);
}
```

Goal: Define a generic add of item to any kind of vector.
Problem: I am getting a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues:

First, make the member functions `public`:

```
class Vector  
{
public:
```

Second,

```
Vector.vec_add(&v,222);
```

should be something like

```
 Vector foo;
 foo.vec_add(v,222);
```

as you are passing a reference, not a pointer, and you must invoke the member function on an instance, in this case `foo`, as the member function is not `static` (think whether you want to make it `static`, in which case you invoke it as `Vector::vec_add`). Full working code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Vector
{
public:
// Use user defined template class for vector handling
    template <class V, class D>
    void vec_add(V &vec, D data)
    {
        vec.push_back(data);
    }
};

int main ()
{
    vector<int> v;  // v is vecor of int elements

    Vector foo;
    foo.vec_add(v, 222);
    std::cout << v.front(); // test it
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acc61c10ae4ced2c)

A good advice is to pick up a book from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the basic features of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother making a class? It would have to be static member function, because you didn't make any Vector objects. Better use normal functions, if you don't have any plans with the class alone:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


template <class V,class D>
void vec_add(V &vec, D data)
{
    vec.push_back(data);
}


int main ()
{
        vector<int> v;  // v is vecor of int elements

        vec_add(v,222);
}
```

Comment: Maybe suggest `namespace`

Answer (score 0):

You have a several problems with your code: your vec_add is private, it is non static, also you call it with pointer to std::vector - while your method accepts a reference. Below is an example with fixed errors, hopefully this is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace std;


class   Vector
{
 // Use user defined template class for vector handling
 public:
    template <class V,class D>
    static void vec_add(V &vec, D data)
    {
            vec.push_back(data);
    }
};

int main ()
{
        vector<int> v;  // v is vecor of int elements

        Vector::vec_add(v,222);
}
```